# Writing and retrieval objects into file using java

Tags: java

Can i write oblects in java into file and retrieve the same?? In c++ we ise wrie function.. can i realize this in java?

In C++ we may use

fin.write((char*)&object,sizeof(classname));

how can i realize this in java.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) to serialize objects to a file (or any other output stream) and [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to read them back in. Objects need to implement the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface to be useful with these classes. Not all objects can be serialized. (For example, it wouldn't make sense or be very useful to serialize a socket.)

Comment: +1: One difference is that Java will serialize references correctly. In C it will copy just the value of the pointer at the time, which isn't useful when deserializing. In Java it will copy the contents of the objects referenced and deserialize it appropriately.